# "SAPUI5 component ID is potentially invalid" on submitting SAPUI5 Application to ABAP System

Tags: deployment, sapui5

When I am trying to upload app to **ABAP-Repository** using `SE38` and `/UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD` I get following error message:

> SAPUI5 component ID SAPUI5.BRUTTOUMSATZ2 in SAPUI5 repository ZBRUTTOUMSATZ is potentially invalid.

Submitting the Project via eclipse brings up the same error message.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue or what might cause this ? I didn't find any documentation on this error message.

The application runs fine when hosted on a local `Jetty-Server`.

Answer (score 1):

A component name should follow these rules, according to the long text of error message /ui5/app_api (019).

- Consist only of alphanumerical characters
- **Contain only lowercase letters in the first except the last segment**
- May contain camel case in the last segment
- Not begin with a number
- Not contain special characters
- Contain a dot as separator of the namespace
- Not be longer than 40 letters for each segment (separated by a dot)

Answer (score 0):

submitting to ABAP-Repository has way more strict naming conventions then mentioned in your answer. I think the application name cannot be longer then 16 signs ... otherwise you cannot submit.

Comment: Is this a comment on my answer? You're right, but that's not what this error is, which it's about the component name not the BSP.

Comment: thanks for the offense. it should state that submitting to abap repository is way more strict then written in your answer. i still expect then naming of "2" and missing "2" or the length of the appname as well as the component to be the problem. btw. is that a question or a comment?

Comment: no offence was intended, I am merely confused, since you mentioned, and I quote: `then mentioned in your answer`.